# Loading a blob(Google app Engine) into PIL or NumPy

Tags: google-app-engine, numpy, blob, python-imaging-library

I'd like to be able to load a blob(image into the Python Image Processing Library or into a numpy array for analysis(such as mean, median, standard deviation) without using the serving url.

Here is my image database
the  t_image_url contains the serving url for the blob

```
from google.appengine.ext import db, blobstore    
class ImageModel(db.Model):
    t_image = blobstore.BlobReferenceProperty(required=True)
    t_imageUrl = db.StringProperty(required = True)
```

here is a segment of what I tried

```
import numpy as np
import Image
import ImageOps
class ImageAnalysisHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self, imageModel_id):
        if self.user:           
            i = ImageModel.get_by_id(int(imageModel_id))
            OpenedImage = Image.open(i.t_image)
            self.render('imageAnalysis.html', imageD = i)
        else:
            self.redirect('login')
```

This obviously didn't work since the Image Module(from the Python Imaging Library) doesn't know how to read blobs. I was wondering if anyone knew how to read in a blob into PIL or a numpy array accurately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [BlobReader class](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/blobreaderclass). It let you read a file store in blobstore with a file-like interface.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to successfully load it into a numpy array.